# drawImage() of canvasrenderingcontext2d not displaying img

Tags: javascript

### I'm trying to learn to use drawImage(), all nodes are created; the image is 1000x500px but never displays

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        var body, canvas, img, cxt;
        body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.style.width = "1000px";
        canvas.style.height = "500px";
        body.appendChild(canvas);
        img = document.createElement("img");
        cxt = canvas.getContext("2d");
        img.onload = function () {
            cxt.drawImage(img,0,0,1000,500,0,0,1000,500);

        }

        img.src = "/clouds.png";
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: do you run the script after page loads? because if this script is located in the head tag as is, it will try to find elements that are not rendered yet. you need to wrap it in a block that runs when the page loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the image I was using had was white.  And so it just so happend that that was the part of the image which I was cropped.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs before your DOM is being loaded, you are trying to append elements to the body before its even created.

you need to wrap your code in a block that will run once the DOM is ready, or better, once the entire window's content is fully loaded:

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/f375zmgy/)**</kbd>

```
window.onload  = function () {
    var body, canvas, img, cxt;
    body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.style.width = "400px";
    canvas.style.height = "400px";
    body.appendChild(canvas);
    img = document.createElement("img");
    cxt = canvas.getContext("2d");
    img.onload = function () {
        cxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 400, 400, 0, 0, 350, 200);
    }
    img.src = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=fde65a5a78c6";
};
```

Comment: I added full DOM, on my script adding window.onload is still unsuccesfull...could it be my arguements

Comment: yes it could, depending on the content of the image you are using. with your arguments part of the image is still supposed to be visible. you can find explanation about the arguments [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp). another thing to keep in mind, is that the image has to exist as well and in the right place. have you tried loading an online image from google to see if it works?